# Selecting array values from specific indexes order by index array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I want to select array values from specific indexes
Now I have this.

```
var xs = new[] { 11,12,13,14,15 };
var ind = new[] { 3,2,1,0 };
var results = xs.Where((x, idx) => ind.Contains(idx)).ToArray();
```

The result is {11,12,13,14}
However, I want my result to be ordered by index array which should be {14,13,12,11}

Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results = ind.Select(i => xs[i]).ToArray();
```

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally hit the wrong vote. Why couldn't I figure this out. Thanks a lot man

Comment: No worries dude.  Linq is a joy when you start to get a feel for it.

Comment: Thanks. I wish I could enjoy it. It's a pain in the ass for me now

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = xs.Zip(ind, (x, i) => new Tuple<int, int>(x, i))
           .OrderBy(t => t.Item2)
           .Select(t => t.Item1)
           .ToArray();
```